# Should I check authentication first or ModelState.IsValid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, modelstate

I have a .NET MVC5 website, where the user is logged in using Microsoft Identity. I have multiple form posts for adding and editing items across the site. I'm looking to know which order I should perform validation in:-

- ModelState.IsValid and then User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
- User.Identity.IsAuthenticated then ModelState.IsValid

I currently have the following code which works, but it seem to be a case of 'the chicken and egg':-

```
var user = UserAccountFunctions.GetUser(User);
if (user != null)
{
    ClientProfile profile = ClientProfile.GetUser(user.Id, db);

    if (profile != null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Should I swap this code round to check the model first, before checking authentication so that I have:-

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = UserAccountFunctions.GetUser(User);
    if (user != null)
    {
        ClientProfile profile = ClientProfile.GetUser(user.Id, db);

        if (profile != null)
        {

            // Do logic here...
        }
    }
}
```

Or is there simply no difference here? I repeat this code a lot throughout the site, so looking for which is the better option? I currently use the top one, because I feel that you shouldn't even attempt to check the model unless they are authenticated?

Any advice here?

Thanks!

Comment: Authentication first, and you do that by adding the `[Authorize]` attribute to your method (or controller)

Comment: use the authorize attribute, like Stephen stated. The validation takes place after authorization because you don't want anauthorized users to see if the model is invalid or not

Comment: [Authorize] does the same as if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) ? Excellent if so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of updating users's email:

```
            [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
            [Authorize]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
            public ActionResult emailupdate(UserEmailEditModel editmodel_post)
            {   
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {   
                  // redirect to email view and show errors
                }

                // check if posted id is the same as stored in session
                if (User.Identity.GetUserId() != editmodel_post.user_id.ToString())
                {
                   // redirect to email view and show errors
                }
            }
```

So

1. Use **Authorize** attribute
2. Use **ValidateAntiForgeryToken** attribute
3. Check **ModelState**
4. Check against session or database